# Getting all members from Prolog list

Tags: prolog

Basically, I made a Prolog program with all stations and the line respectively

```
station(station_name,[Line]). // My facts//
```

so to list out the stations in the line entered, I made a rule

```
line(Line,ListofStations):- station(ListofStations,[Line]).
```

Any station with more than one Line isnt being displayed
example

```
OxfordStreet,[central,bakerloo] // more than one member in a list
```

The above example isnt working

Comment: `[Line]` is a list of just one element. `[central, bakerloo]` will not match it.

Comment: Show us more of your code. I really hope you don't have variables in your facts. Show us an example of the fact that is not being matched. @lurker is right, but without more code we can't tell you what you should do.

Comment: station(oxford_circus,[bakerloo,central,victoria]).
station(embankment,[bakerloo,northern]).
station(elephantandcastle,[bakerloo]).
station(nottingHill_gate,[central]).
station(lancaster_gate,[central]).
station(tottenham_court_road,[central]).
station(chancery_lane,[central]).
station(liverpool_street,[central,metropolitan]).
station(bethnal_green,[central]).

Comment: The facts which wont match are oxford circus and liverpool street because they have more than one line